# Add a selected class to a list when scrolling past the offset of set of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, offset

I think I'm close, but I'm having trouble trying to finalize this. Basically when you scroll down to each image, the div containing that image's offset from the top of the window (-500 as a buffer) would add a `.selected` class to the list element on the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/H6RTs/ is my example

Here is the code where basically the magic happens (sort of):

```
        $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        // What the current px is from vertical scroll
        var scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
        // They scrolled more than the original offset
        if (scrollY > menuTop) {
            if (menuClone.parent().length === 0) {
                $('#js-current-products').each(function(index, value) {
                    var newIndex = index + 1;
                    var currentProduct = $('.js-current-product-' + newIndex).offset().top - 500;
                    if (scrollY > currentProduct) {
                        $('.js-product-' + newIndex).addClass('selected');
                    }
                });

                stickyDiv.addClass(posFixed).width(clonedWidth);
                menuClone.after(stickyDiv.parent());

            }
        } else {
            $('#js-product-menu li').first().removeClass('selected');
            stickyDiv.removeClass(posFixed);
            menuClone.remove();
        }

    });
```

It'll add the class to the first list item, but not the other ones (so I guess it keeps focusing on `$('.js-current-product-1')` instead of iterating through all of them (which would be 3).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can't seem to debug without the browser crashing.. Have you considered using a plugin like waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) where you bind and element, and make changes when they are scrolled by. Not that there is anything wrong with doing it yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only iterate over all elements which are identified by `id="js-current-products"`. Only one element matches this selector. So

```
if (scrollY > menuTop) {
    if (menuClone.parent().length === 0) {
        $('#js-current-products').each(function(index, value) {
             // matches only one product ....
```

should be

```
if (scrollY > menuTop) {
    if (menuClone.parent().length === 0) {
        $('#js-current-products div.border').each(function(index, value) {
             // matches all products, but has to use div.border, since 
             // you changed your class names....
```

or something similar. Also you shouldn't change classnames to create unique ones for each element. They're *class names*, not *identifiers*.

```
$('#js-current-products .js-current-product').each(function(index, value) {
    var newIndex = index + 1;
    $(this).attr('id','js-current-product-' + newIndex);
});
```

If you don't abuse classes then you can also remove your `.selected` class very easily:

```
if (scrollY > currentProduct) {
    $('#js-product-menu li').removeClass('selected');
    $('#js-product-' + newIndex).addClass('selected');     
}
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/H6RTs/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. The reason I used classes on those divs was because mainly this was hacked together, and I assumed that the person who'll be using it won't be wrapping the images in an `<ul>` as list elements, so I needed some way to target all of them. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

**#EDIT - The way Zeta loop through is much cleaner :D#**
1:

```
$('#js-current-products').each(function(index, value) {
    var newIndex = index + 1;
    var currentProduct = $('.js-current-product-' + newIndex).offset().top - 500;
    if (scrollY > currentProduct) {
        $('.js-product-' + newIndex).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

Your just looping through the container of the images, of which there is only one, so what you need to do is loop the the images themselves. One way would be to add the class `prod` to them when you loop through and give them an index, ie:

```
$('#js-current-products .js-current-product').each(function(index, value) {
    var newIndex = index + 1;
    $(this).removeClass('js-current-product').addClass('js-current-product-' + newIndex).addClass('prod');
});
```

**#EDIT#**

2:
You also need to remove the `selected` class when you scroll back up, this is easily done by adding an else to the test condition, ie:

```
if (scrollY > currentProduct) {
    $('.js-product-' + newIndex).addClass('selected');
    console.log(newIndex);
} else {
    $('.js-product-' + newIndex).removeClass('selected');
}
```

I'm pretty sure that's all, take a look at the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/H6RTs/3/

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: Thanks Charlie. Yeah I happened to just leave off the removing the select class as this was just a quick hackjob. Thanks for the help + explanation. Repped.